pyspark dataframe keep the old active status for each group of data
I have the following pyspark dataframe :



ID
Name
datecreation
Status




A
nameA1
2024-12-01
Active


B
nameB1
2024-12-10
Active


B
nameB2
2024-11-01
Deleted


C
nameC1
2024-11-01
Active


C
nameC2
2024-10-01
Active


C
nameC3
2024-09-02
Deleted


C
nameC4
2024-12-03
Deleted


D
nameD1
2024-11-01
Deleted


D
nameD2
2024-11-02
Deleted


D
nameD3
2024-11-03
Deleted



I need to generate a new dataframe , that will keep by group of "ID", the row with the Oldest Active status, and if we dont have an active status then keep the oldest row.
at the end it will generate :



ID
Name
datecreation
Status




A
nameA1
2024-12-01
Active


B
nameB1
2024-12-10
Active


C
nameC2
2024-10-01
Active


D
nameD1
2024-11-01
Deleted



Thank you

You can try this
Edited : After feedback
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [
    ('A', 'nameA1', '2024-12-01', 'Active'),
    ('B', 'nameB1', '2024-12-10', 'Active'),
    ('B', 'nameB2', '2024-11-01', 'Deleted'),
    ('C', 'nameC1', '2024-11-01', 'Active'),
    ('C', 'nameC2', '2024-10-01', 'Active'),
    ('C', 'nameC3', '2024-09-02', 'Deleted'),
    ('C', 'nameC4', '2024-12-03', 'Deleted'),
    ('D', 'nameD1', '2024-11-01', 'Deleted'),
    ('D', 'nameD2', '2024-11-02', 'Deleted'),
    ('D', 'nameD3', '2024-11-03', 'Deleted')
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Name", "datecreation", "Status"])

# Convert datecreation to a proper date type
df = df.withColumn("datecreation", F.to_date(df["datecreation"], "yyyy-MM-dd"))

# Window spec to partition by ID and order by datecreation (oldest first)
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("datecreation")

# Get the oldest Active row for each ID, if any exists
df_active = df.filter(df["Status"] == "Active").withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(window_spec))

# Get the oldest row regardless of status for each ID (this will be our fallback)
df_oldest = df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(window_spec))

# Get the first Active row per ID, or if no Active rows exist, fallback to the oldest row
df_final = df_active.filter(df_active["row_num"] == 1).union(
    df_oldest.filter((df_oldest["row_num"] == 1) & ~df_oldest["ID"].isin(df_active.select("ID").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()))
)

# Drop the row_num column
df_final = df_final.drop("row_num")

# Show the final result
df_final.show()

Output that I got which matches your expected output:


I just tried the code it doesnt give the expected result, thank you for trying

Thanks, I have edited and tested and seems like it now matches your expected output.can you check?

With groupby and collect-list for the resulting array of structs, you can prepend one flag field (is_active) to distinguish between "Active" and other Status and use it as the first sorting field and then datecreation as the 2nd sorting field with sort_array function and then take the first array item:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupby('ID') \
  .agg(
    F.sort_array(
      F.collect_list(
        F.struct(
            F.expr("IF(Status='Active',0,1) as is_active")
          , 'datecreation'
          , 'Name'
          , 'Status'
        )
      )
    )[0].alias('dta')
  ).select('ID', "dta.*").show()
+---+---------+------------+------+-------+
| ID|is_active|datecreation|  Name| Status|
+---+---------+------------+------+-------+
|  B|        0|  2024-12-10|nameB1| Active|
|  D|        1|  2024-11-01|nameD1|Deleted|
|  C|        0|  2024-10-01|nameC2| Active|
|  A|        0|  2024-12-01|nameA1| Active|
+---+---------+------------+------+-------+

As a side-note: you can replace sort_array(...)[0] with array_min(...).
Or use array_sort function with a customized comparator:
df.groupby('ID') \
  .agg(
    F.expr("""
      array_sort(
        collect_list((Name,datecreation,Status)), 
        (l,r) -> IF((l.Status!='Active',l.datecreation) > (r.Status!='Active',r.datecreation),1,-1)
      )[0] as dta
    """)
).select('ID', "dta.*").show()
+---+------+------------+-------+
| ID|  Name|datecreation| Status|
+---+------+------------+-------+
|  B|nameB1|  2024-12-10| Active|
|  D|nameD1|  2024-11-01|Deleted|
|  C|nameC2|  2024-10-01| Active|
|  A|nameA1|  2024-12-01| Active|
+---+------+------------+-------+


We have two different ID groups, one that has Active Status rows and one that does not.
active_status = F.col("Status") == "Active"
# Find IDs that have `Active` Status rows.
has_active = [
    x.ID for x in 
    df.filter(active_status).select("ID").distinct().collect()
]

# We'll be doing the same aggregations for both groups.
agg_funcs = (
    F.min_by("Name", "datecreation").alias("Name"),
    F.min("datecreation").alias("datecreation"),
    F.first_value("Status").alias("Status"),
)

# Calculate the two groups separately and Union the results. 
output = (
    df.where(active_status).groupby("ID").agg(*agg_funcs)
      .unionAll(
    df.where(~F.col("ID").isin(has_active)).groupby("ID").agg(*agg_funcs)
    )
)
output.show()

Output:
+---+------+------------+-------+
| ID|  Name|datecreation| Status|
+---+------+------------+-------+
|  A|nameA1|  2024-12-01| Active|
|  B|nameB1|  2024-12-10| Active|
|  C|nameC2|  2024-10-01| Active|
|  D|nameD1|  2024-11-01|Deleted|
+---+------+------------+-------+

